# Using Model with none MVC application

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, model, custom-controls

I'm trying to use a Model with my Asp.net page. But im not using MVC. I get an error when trying to inherit the model from a customcontrol. The error is

> ViewModel: interface name expected.

```
public partial class CustomControl : UserControl, ViewModel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do multiple [inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx) in C#. `UserControl` and `ViewModel` are both classes and you are only able to inherit from a single class.

You can however implement as many [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) as you like.

Comment: What do you mean. I can inherit a class and IDataErrorInfo with no problem.

Comment: Yes, because IDataErrorInfo is an interface.